# передача модели из View в Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
public ActionResult Create(List<DetailOrderViewModel> order)
{
    return View();
}
```

Order может содержать несколько позиций. Изначально на View есть несколько полей, которые отвечают за одну позицию в заказе

```
<div class="position">
    @Html.DropDownList("order[0].Title", ViewBag.Inventory as SelectList, new { @class = "input-sm" })
    @Html.TextBox("order[0].Quantity", "1", new { @class = "input-sm", type = "number", min = "1" })
    @Html.TextBox("order[0].Comment", "", new { @class = "input-sm", placeholder = "Введите комментарий" })
    <input type="button" value="Удалить позицию" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-del"/>
</div>
```

Есть кнопка добавить позицию и удалить позицию, обязательно ли соблюдать правильное индексирование при отправке заказа контроллеру?

Comment: Вопрос не понятен: 1) Говорите про отправку заказа, а приведен код по удалению. 2) `... соблюдать правильное индексирование` попробуй по другому сформулировать этот момент.

Comment: Да, должны соблюдать иначе при сабмите формы на сервер придут не все данные.